# nested aligns inside a command, inside math?

Tags: macros, align

I got a few commands that are nested, two of which work, but the last one does not.

```
\newcommand{\trine}[3]
{
    {#1} \times {#2} \times {#3}
}
\newcommand{\MchainSub}[9]
{
    k &= {#2} &\to M[{#1},{#2}] &+& M[{#3},{#4}] &+& {#5} \\[-1em]
      &       &    {#6} &+& {#7} &+& {#8} &=& {#9}\\
}
\newcommand{\Mchain}[2]
{
    \begin{aligned}
        \begin{aligned}
            {#1}
        \end{aligned} &=\left\{
        \begin{aligned}
            {#2}
        \end{aligned} \right.
    \end{aligned}
}
```

Does not work:

```
\[
\begin{array}{l}
    \Mchain{
        M[i, j] \\[-1em]
        A, k=i
    }{
        \MchainSub{i}{k}{l}{j}{ \trine{a}{b}{c} }{x}{y}{z}{w}
        \MchainSub{i}{k}{l}{j}{ \trine{a}{b}{c} }{x}{y}{z}{w}
    } %<- here is error
\end{array}
\]
```

Does work:

```
\[
\begin{array}{l}
    \begin{aligned}
    \begin{aligned}
        M[i, j] \\[-1em]
        A, k=i
    \end{aligned} &=\left\{
    \begin{aligned}
        \MchainSub{i}{k}{l}{j}{ \trine{a}{b}{c} }{x}{y}{z}{w}
        \MchainSub{i}{k}{l}{j}{ \trine{a}{b}{c} }{x}{y}{z}{w}
    \end{aligned} \right.
    \end{aligned}
\end{array}
\]
```

[image]

Why does the first one not work? Since I will be repeating the \Mchain with the nested \MchainSub's and \trine's many times my macro method would be far faster to work with.

I keep on getting eror missing }. missing { ...

Comment: unrelated to the error but are you sure you want `&=&` and `&+&` etc in an `aligned` you haven't provided a usable example so I haven't seen the output but I would assume this makes rather odd spacing: alignment cells are aligned alternately left and right.

Comment: I added an image to show you what It comes out as. And since I am doing about 25 more of these, with more than 2 nested \MchainSubs, doing a macro is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

you have `{#2}` with unwanted braces so after `#2` is `\MchainSub` which inserts `&` you end up with `{` in the first cell and `}` in the last which is an error.

You should probably remove all the braces around your `#2` etc, as even when not generating errors, extra braces in math mode affect the spacing.

Comment: Well, I feel dumb, my habit of wrapping all my args like that just bit me in the ass. Thanks though.